# Finding real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

What are the real roots of equation x^3 + x - 1 ?

I tried to factor the equation but it doesn't help me here. I noticed that f(0) = -1 and f(1) = 1. So there must exist at least one real root in-between 0 and 1 but I am not able to find it.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Do you know the [rational root theorem](rational root theorem)?  In this case, the only rational roots could possibly be $1$ and $-1$, neither of which are roots (so the polynomial doesn't have any rational roots).  Do you know [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)?  This will work in this case, but it'll be messy.

Comment: Well, it hasn't got a particularly nice real root.  Are you sure you aren't intended to count the real roots or something along those lines?

Comment: The real solution is not trivial, you are good for Cardan!

Comment: $$x_1=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(9+\sqrt{93}\right)}}{3^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3
   \left(9+\sqrt{93}\right)}}$$

Comment: I was asked to count the real roots but I don't know cardano's formula or such.

Comment: To count the real roots: Look at the derivative, is it always positive?  Could you have two real roots if the derivative is always positive?

Comment: The task of *counting* the real roots is **much much easier** than the task of *calculating* them.

Comment: I just looked Descartes method which says just count the number of times the sign changes. I don't understand why does it work.

Comment: @Michael Burr, if a function is continuous and if it has 2 real roots then there will be a real number c such that f' (c) = 0 right ? Because to get 2 real roots the function needs to change the direction at some point of time and the derivative is zero at that point where the function changes its direction.

Comment: Yes, your argument for $f'(c)=0$ works (or use the mean value theorem).

Comment: Also Descartes' rule of signs doesn't say that the number of roots is the number of times the sign changes, it says that the number of sign changes is an *upper bound* the number of *positive* roots and the error is even.  If you want to find out more about Descartes' rule of signs, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @Michael Burr, how can we use mean value theorem here ? Can you please explain ?

Comment: Actually, Rolle's theorem is enough, but if $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a\not=b$, then by the MVT, there is a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ so that $f'(c)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

While definitely not the most efficient method for finding the root(s) of a given cubic equation, there *is* a general formula you can use to solve $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

$x = (q+(q^2+(r-p^2)^3)^{1/2})^{1/3}+(q-(q^2+(r-p^2)^3)^{1/2})^{1/3}+p$

where

$p = \frac{-b}{3a}$,

$q = p^3+\frac{bc-3ad}{6a^2}$, and

$r = \frac{c}{3a}$

With this, you should be able to find the exact form of the unique real solution to $x^3+x - 1 = 0$